# SQL Server: XPATH Query failing

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I am working in SQL Server Management Studio on a stored procedure. There is a column containing XML that I am trying to access with XPATH but I get this error:

> Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support`

I read the docs on convert and importing xml but no luck.

To be clear, I have XML stored in a column in a table, and now want to access it with xpath after querying it into memory in a stored procedure. Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your most likely getting this because somewhere inside of your XML you are using a document definition such as this:   ([MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server) of DTD)

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC [<!ATTLIST elem1 attr1 CDATA "defVal1">]><elem1>January</elem1>
```

Microsoft blocks this by default as it creates a potential security hole.  The convert with style option 2 message is telling you that you can enable partial support for DTD in order to process this XML through use of the [CONVERT function as it relates to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

I don't have personal experience with doing that so I can't offer more than the link to MSDN.

The only other option is to enable full DTD support on the server which Microsoft does not recommend.

Comment: Yep, right on, thanks.  After looking at the docs the command goes like this `convert(XML, myXmlAsString,2)`

Comment: Why is this a potential security hole?