# How to download a webpage and parse in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, web-scraping, dynamic-sql

I am simply trying to download a webpage and store it in an accessible format in SQL Server 2012. I have resorted to using dynamic SQL, but perhaps there is a cleaner, easier way to do this.  I have been able to successfully download the htm files to my local drive using the below code, but I am having difficulty working with the html itself. I am trying to convert the webpage to XML and parse from there, but I think I am not addressing the HTML to XML conversion properly.

I get the following error, "Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support"

```
DECLARE @URL      NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @Ticker   NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @DynamicTickerNumber INT
SET @DynamicTickerNumber = 1

CREATE TABLE Parsed_HTML(
[Date] DATETIME
,[Ticker]    VarChar (8)
,[NodeName] VarChar (50)
,[Value]    NVARCHAR (50));

WHILE @DynamicTickerNumber <= 2
BEGIN

SET @Ticker = (SELECT [Ticker] FROM [Unique Tickers Yahoo] WHERE [Unique Tickers Yahoo].[Ticker Number]= @DynamicTickerNumber)

SET @URL ='http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=' + @Ticker + '+Key+Statistics'

DECLARE @cmd      NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @tOutput  TABLE(data NVARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @file     NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @file='D:\Ressources\Execution Model\Execution Model for SQL\DB Temp\quoteYahooHTML.htm'
SET @cmd ='powershell "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('''+@URL+''','''+@file+''')"'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output

CREATE TABLE XmlImportTest
(
xmlFileName VARCHAR(300),
xml_data xml
);

DECLARE @xmlFileName VARCHAR(300)
SELECT  @xmlFileName = 'D:\Ressources\Execution Model\Execution Model for SQL\DB Temp\quoteYahooHTML.htm'


EXEC('
INSERT INTO XmlImportTest(xmlFileName, xml_data)

SELECT ''' + @xmlFileName + ''', xmlData 
FROM
(
SELECT  * 
FROM    OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @xmlFileName + ''' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA
) AS FileImport (XMLDATA)
')

DECLARE @x XML;
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @x = (SELECT xml_data FROM XmlImportTest)
SET @string = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @x, 1);

INSERT INTO [Parsed_HTML] ([NodeName], [Value])
SELECT [NodeName], [Value] FROM dbo.XMLTable(@string)
--above references XMLTable Parsing function that works consistently

END
```

Unfortunately this needs to be run within the confines of SQL Server, and my understanding is that the HTML Agility Pack is not immediately compatible. I also notice that the intermediate table, XMLimportTest, never gets populated, so this is likely not a function of malformed HTML.

Comment: HTML not always can be converted into XML. It could contain things like an unclosed <br> tag or a script containing < or > that cannot be parsed. That's why I use scraping libraries like HTML AgilityPack. Moreover some web pages have HTML syntax errors e.g. an unclosed div or p tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: XPATH Query failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981636/sql-server-xpath-query-failing)

Comment: The code your are using seems to be OK... If this is your own web site done in clean XHTML you might cast it to XML and rely on its validity. But in any other case you can't. Try to import the file into your table into a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` first. If it allows you to cast it (try `CONVERT(XML, YourData, 2)`), be happy! If not, you'll have to parse your data out (`SUBSTRING`, `PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX` ...)

Comment: Thanks, Shnugo. It allows me to cast but the conversion throws an error. I assume this is because the HTML is not clean. Let me ask you, is there an easy way to isolate one small piece of HTML data if I know the html tagging?

Comment: Plese use the edit option to add sample HTML and expected output to your question

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't.

SQL is very good for some things but for downloading and parsing HTML it's a terrible choice. In your example you're using PowerShell to download the file, why not parse the HTML in PowerShell too? Then you could write the parsed data into something like a CSV file and load that in using OPENROWSET.

Another option, still not using SQL but a bit more within SQL Server might be to use a .Net SP via [SQL CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx).

As a few of the comments point out, if you could guarantee the HTML was well formed XML then you could use SQL XML functionality to parse it, but web pages are rarely well formed XML so this would be a risky choice.