# SQL Agent Job error when trying to run SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-agent

I have an SSIS package which when I run in VS it runs fine. I have changed the `protection level` to `Dont Save Sensitive`. I have also given any files related permission to be overwritten by the sql agent job account.

The error I am getting is:

```
Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.
```

So far I have got the impression that I need to change the code but if the code was really a problem my package wouldnt run in the first place which clearly isnt the case.

How can I reslve this?

Comment: Does this help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981636/sql-server-xpath-query-failing

Comment: I've already had a look at that. 1- I don't find anything similar to that code he mentioned in answer and 2 - I dont understand why I would need to change my code for it to work because it runs perfectly find if I run it manually (unless its an absolute necessity to change code)